# WooCommerce Customer/Order XML Export Suite error when exporting xml file

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

Our hard disk went full yesterday and we solved the issue by increasing disk space on the web server. All the sites were working again it seemed.

Few hours later, I logged in and noticed one of the sites was showing errors. We have fixed most of the errors that arose since then except for one single error remaining with WooCommerce Customer/Order XML Export Suite plugin.

WooCommerce orders are being received, but XML files are not being transported to the warehouse any more. When I run a test export, I get the following error:

> Test failed: FTP error: fopen(/tmp/test.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

What can we do to rectify this?

Comment: This was able to solve my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43368849/error-when-trying-to-update-wordpress-plugins

Answer (score 0):

Check error_log to see if you have write permissions for /tmp
Or, for any warnings that look like the xml file messed up
Also check the /tmp isn't full by typing df -h